# JavaScript async help - Google Maps JavaScript API to calculate directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am fairly new to JavaScript, so here's a summary of my problem for context. The user enters two locations, `originInput` and `destinationInput`. The Places API then gets the Latlng for the locations, which works as expected. My problem comes when trying to use these results to calculate the directions between the two. As far as I can tell, the problem is that the `calcRoute` function is executing *before* the Places objects are returned from the Places API, which takes time. I don't know how to get around this, assuming that is the problem.

So far, I have tried to append the value that is returned from the Places API to an array, then use this as a parameter for the Directions API.

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="originInput"></input>
<input type="text" id="destinationInput"></input>
<button onclick="initMap()"></button> 

<div id="map"></div>
```

Relevant JS:

```js
// function takes user input and gets back a place object from the API
function getPlaces() {
  var originInput = document.getElementById("originInput");
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById("destinationInput");
  var requests = {
    request1: {
      query: originInput.value,
      fields: ['name', 'geometry']
    },
    request2: {
      query: destinationInput.value,
      fields: ['name', 'geometry']
    }
  };
  placeService.findPlaceFromQuery(requests.request1, callback);
  placeService.findPlaceFromQuery(requests.request2, callback);
  // Calls calcRoute function to display the route between points
  calcRoute(resultsLatlng[0], resultsLatlng[1]);
}

// callback function for findPlaceFromQuery
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    resultsLatlng.push(results[0].geometry.location);
    console.log(resultsLatlng)
    }
  }

  // Function to access the directionsService API and display the route
function calcRoute(start, end) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }
  directionsService.route(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result)
      console.log(result)
    }
  })
  console.log(resultsLatlng)
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/adam1lake/qjcou20h/ for the code.
Just put your API key in the script tag at the bottom of the HTML and it should work.

If you run the code on the jsfiddle, there will be an error as the directions API isn't receiving a Latlng object as its parameters for start and end location. Please feel free to correct any of my other code on that jsfiddle :)

Comment: Please don't only post code on jsfiddle but also add the minimal example as code blocks on your question. (Assume jsfiddle goes extinct, your question would not be readable then anymore.) You can even create a JavaScript code example within stackoverflow editor.

Comment: Thank you @k0pernikus for the advice, I have added some code :)

Comment: You are calling the calcRoute function before the callbacks for the placeService had time to run, just make a small test. Create a global variable that works like a counter, start at 0 and within the callback for the placeService increment the counter, and check if the counter is 2, if it is we are sure that we are in the second callback and you have all the information you need and only here you call the calcRoute" if this works you know where the problem lies, now is just finding the best solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is dealing with callbacks, asynchronous code, and knowing when the data will be returned. You are correct when you say that the `calcRoute` is executing before the Places object is returned. There are some [great](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) [resources](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff) on understanding asynchronous javascript to read and research.

One way to fix that would be to update your callback function to check how many elements exist in your `resultsLatlng` array. If it has two elements (the start location and the end location), then calculate the route from the results.

```
// callback function for findPlaceFromQuery
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    resultsLatlng.push(results[0].geometry.location);
    if (resultsLatlng.length == 2) { // New code
      calcRoute(resultsLatlng[0], resultsLatlng[1]);
    }
  }
}
```